# Write a single poly-linear string to multiple lines in .txt

Tags: python, regex

I have encountered a strange problem which I am struggling to resolve. When I run a `re.findall()` through a .txt file, and then try to print and write the results. all of the results I would expect appear, but they do so in different formats.
The code (modified from a similar thread I found earlier):

```
import re

with open ('test.txt') as text:
    text = text.read()
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
for i in match:
    with open ('list.txt', 'a') as dest:
        i = str(i)
        print(i)
        dest.write(i)
```

The interpreter then produces the result:

```
a@a
b@b
c@c
```

which is exactly what I would expect it to do, given the contents of test.txt.
However, list.txt reads:

```
(generic existing text goes here)
a@ab@bc@c
```

while I want it to (and believe it should) read

```
(generic existing text goes here)
a@a
b@b
c@c
```

I've tried using `str.writelines.()` in place of `str.write()` but this was not helpful. What differences between `print()` and `str.write()` are causing this ambiguity, and how would one go about avoiding it.

N.B. I am 99% sure that line 8 `i = str(i)` serves no purpose, but I've left it in because it's what I've been doing. Not really sure why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with your last comment. What `str(i)` does is it converts `i` to its string representation (which is defined in `i`'s class's `__str__` method). If you call `str(4)` you get `'4'`, for example. This is unnecessary in this case because `re.findall` returns a list of strings [as per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

As for your actual issue: you're missing the newlines. I would also prefer to open the file fewer times than you are.

Perhaps try:

```
import re

with open ('test.txt') as text:
    text = text.read()
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
with open('list.txt', 'a') as dest:
    for i in match:
        print(i)
        dest.write(i + '\n')
```

(You can also remove the `print(i)` line if you don't want to see the output in the console every time a write is done.)

Comment: Thanks mate! I thought I'd tried that before to no avail... Must have forgotten the space or something amateurish like that. Anyway, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Gotta be an egg before you can grok. Happy coding! :)